# When does the Spanish word order differ?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sintaxis, orden-de-palabras

I get that there is a differece between a statement and a question. E.g:

> Juan viene. 》 ¿Viene Juan?

Pero a veces es diferente.

Hay una canción que se dice: "*PR somos tú y yo*". ¿Por qué no dice "*tú y yo somos de PR*"?

Este es un ejemplo que no entiendo.

Comment: Note that songs are places where the style matters, and swapping subject and object is quite common there.

Comment: También existe «Viene Juan» y «¿Juan viene?».  El orden depende del contexto y el énfasis o contraste que se le quiere dar a la oración.  Ojo: «PR somos tú y yo» y «tú y yo somos de PR» *no son equivalentes*.  «PR somos tú y yo» es equivalente de «tú y yo somos PR» (no hay «de»), y «tú y yo somos de PR» es equivalente de «de PR somos tú y yo»

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What is the common construction of questions spoken by native speakers of Spanish?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15830/what-is-the-common-construction-of-questions-spoken-by-native-speakers-of-spanis). Bottom line: it's common to invert the order for questions (i. e. verb-subject), but in Spanish word order is free so keeping a subject-verb structure is also okay, and could be the preferred option for, for example, long questions (as in the question linked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the order without problems. In Spanish, the phrasal structure is very flexible.

The phrase:

*"Juan fue ayer al cine con Ana"*

It has the following valid forms:

*"Al cine con Ana, fue ayer Juan"*

*"Ayer, Juan fue al cine con Ana"*

*"Con Ana, al cine fue ayer Juan"*

Anyone speaking spanish will understand and accept all of them as correct.

Comment: So there is no rule when to or when to  not do it? (Except with questions)

Comment: Exactly, in spanish the phrases have two parts, subject and predicate(That includes the verb) and it's accepted in any order if you respect that. This is actually a rule.

This is valid for basic phrases, not for imperative, interrogative, negative or excalmative.

Comment: 100% agree @guifa: "El orden depende del contexto y el énfasis o contraste que se le quiere dar a la oración" Put the word you want to focus on at the beggining: _Al cine con Ana, fue ayer Juan_ and _Ayer, Juan fue al cine con Ana_ focus on _cine_ and _ayer_ respectively

Comment: Actually, there's no real restriction even in interrogative.  Subject-verb order in questions is very typical of Caribbean Spanish:  *¿Cómo tú estás?*

Comment: "Al cine con Ana, fue ayer Juan" This sounds like Yoda.  "Obi-Wan to the movies with his padawan went". You do understand but you won't use it in everyday talking. It is good for poetry or space movies.